# Trying to use Content Editor WebPart

Tags: javascript, web-part, content-editor-web-part

I have been trying to use content editor web part to have when someone trys to open a PDF in my document library, It wont open in same window.... However i do not know how or where to enter the Java Script. Is there a How to guide for this to follow.

Thanks in advance for anyone comment.

Regards,
Simon

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add your document library as a web part on the page. Also add the content editor web part in the same page but go to the web properties and select the tool bar as none so users wont be able to see that there is a dummy web part.

Now either write a script in the text file and link it to the Content editor web part by uploading it to one of the libraries or just write with in the html section of the web part by selecting via ribbon.